# Set the text size (font size) in the ConEmu PowerShell window?

Tags: powershell, conemu

I have opened PowerShell in ConEmu. The text size is too small for a presentation. How do we increase it? I have tried the following ConEmu Settings: Size & Pos, Appearance, Text Cursor. I haven't found it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`ConEmu` > `Settings` > `Main` contains font settings. We have to click right on `Main` rather than one of its children.[image]

Answer (score 11):

Another easy way to change the font size, especially temporarily for a presentation, is to hold the CTRL key and then move the mouse wheel.  The size will increase and decrease as you move the wheel up and down.

This trick works in Chrome too, btw.

Comment: What if I don't have a mouse wheel, e.g. on laptop or tablet?

Comment: If you have a touch screen, you can pinch zoom (both in ConEmu and Chrome).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I Tried the classic ctrl-NumPad+ -trick and it didn't work.